# How to open a CSV file in excel with arabic in it

Tags: excel, csv, arabic

Hi Please help how to open a CSV file which has arabic in it. Have tried few things, but nothing seem to be working. It is displaying junk values.

Links which i tried:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: The following steps should work

Rename .csv to .txt
Open .txt file from Excel (don't do it with right click on file then open with Excel), Excel will open a Text Import Wizard dialog, ask ask for the format of .txt file, including character encoding of text file.
Rename .txt back to .csv after your edit is finished. There are  3 choices for Arabic characters.

Comment: I'm unable to install it, in the language -> proofing its showing not installed

Comment: I shall revert back to you after q quick check

Comment: I have been able to work it out. Difficult to explain through comments. Should I put my Answer.

Comment: I have posted with step wise comment, Please review situation in regard to comma breaks, line feed and page break adjustments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Rename File Extension with Arabic Character from .csv to txt say MS DOS.
2. Here is the sample file 
   [image: arabic 3]

When you first save the File from csv to txt after renaming it, a pop up dialog will appear
[image: arabic2]

3    Click cancel then a dialog box will appear

[image: arabic2]

4. Save the txt file in Dir and rename to csv.

   Here you will get choices for arabic characters.Arabic 708.720, 28596
5. save the file and rename to txt, it opens with proper characters as shown below. But please ensure that , separation character is maintained, Some adjustment at line breaks and page  may be required

[image: arabic1]

Comment: @anagha s Could  you get it right or difficulties still. i selected UNICODE Characters.

Comment: Its still not converting

Comment: @anaghas Can you upload sample file to some site like dropbox, onedrive etc. So that I may test at my end.

Comment: tried with utf-8, instead of arabic. Now its working

Comment: @anaghas Please accept my answer, if you consider my efforts useful to you.